# understand ssl files and mechanisme

Tags: java, ssl, openssl

hello I'd like to have someone explain me how ssl works and most importantly explaine me what are all these file extension and what are their purposes for exemple I'm trying to connect to a kafka and i had a scrip that did an extract of secrets in mu kubernetes cluster for my kafka , and I got multiple files and don't know what tey're used for : so if someon can explaine me what is .trustore .keystore .pem .p12 .key .crt .ca.crt ... thank you I know that it might be vague but I'm new to using ssl and kafka so It would really help me if someone has some basic explanation of this .

Thank you for your help

Comment: Kafka is an implementation detail. Removed tag since this is purely a Java TLS/JKS question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very complex topic and you should use Google. I'll try to answer here, but if you don't understand SSL, PKI and asymmetric encryption concepts you'll probably get lost in my explanation. You can find videos on Youtube and plenty of tutorial and explanations around internet.

Each SSL certificate is made from two parts:

1. SSL certificate itself - this is a public part, it contains Common Name, some other important information about certificate and its owner. Most important part is probably the PUBLIC KEY and CA signature
2. Private key - this is essentially the password - it is a private part and you must never share it with anyone

Private and Public keys are mathematically bound each to other. What you encrypt with one key can be decrypted with another key. Who has PRIVATE key can easily derive PUBLIC key from it but it doesn't work another way around. This is principle of asymmetric encryption.

The certificate and key are just two files. The extension doesn't really matter. But for convenience `.key` suffix is used for the private key. For certificate, we commonly use `.crt`, `.pem` or `.der`.

The important thing is how the certificate and private key is ENCODED. It can be PEM-encoded or DER-encoded:

- PEM: this is human readable format. You can tell the PEM encoded certificate because first line contains `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` line.
- DER: this is binary format. If you open this file in editor it will be bunch of non-readable nonsense as it's just bunch of 0s and 1s

Now you can see where suffixes `.der` and `.pem` come from. `.crt` suffix is used just as an alternative to `.pem` suffix. So that everyone can tell 'this most likely the certificate'.

The important part about the every certificate is that it must be signed by someone. The someone is Certification Authority. Certification Authority is just another public/private key pair. It's owned by some organization that's highly trusted. Certification authority can use their private key to sign your certificate. Their private key is super secure. What you can get to is the public key and this is what `ca.crt`, `ca.pem` or `ca.der` contains. The important part is that you can use CA public key in order to verify the signature done by their private key. The signature is part of your certificate.

There are publicly trusted certification authorities out there in the internet and every web browser trusts them. Those are organizations that are audited and commonly trusted.

You can create Certification Authority certificate and private key by yourself. Problem is nobody will trust it when you use it to sign the certificate. This is why you must take `ca.crt` file and provide it as well. Together with your server certificate `whatever.crt` you must also send `ca.crt` and tell the person who's trying to verify it 'hey! this is the CA I used to sign that certificate please trust it'. And it's up to them to trust it or not :)

Now `.p12` extension. This is yet another form of the certificate. PKCS#12 is a certificate 'container' or 'archive'. You can put your private key file (`.key`) your certificate file (`.crt`, `.pem` or `.der` file) and "put" them together to one file. You can think of it as ZIP archive but obviously it's not ZIP file. You can protect it with password too. You can use `openssl` utility to create pkcs#12 container.

`truststore` and `keystore` are Java concepts. I personally hate them because they just overcomplicate things and don't add any value. Majority of Java applications can work with pem/crt/key/p12/der files. Kafka recently also included support but it's sort of half baked I'd say.

`truststore` is also 'archive' or 'container' that contains the 'certificates to trust'. In other words it contains Certification Authority files (one or multiple). So `ca.crt` file goes there (not its private key! just the `ca.crt`). It can contain multiple certificates. When Java application starts up it will read the file and will trust any certificate signed by certification authorities inside the file (for example when you connect from that java to some SSL protected webpage or server). Truststore is usually protected by a password.

`keystore` is also 'archive' or 'container'. You create keystore from `.p12` archive. So the keystore contains same things as `.p12` file. The certificate + its private key. Keystore is usually protected by a password.

`keystore` and `truststore` are created using Java `keytool` utility. And as mentioned you need `.p12` file to create them so usual process is:

1. I will use `openssl` to generate private key
2. I will use `openssl` to generate CSR (`.csr` suffix) or certificate signing request file - this file is unsigned certificate
3. I will send `.csr` file to Certification Authority, they will sign it and provide back `.crt` or `.pem` or `.der` file (or even all of them so I can pick). They will also send you `ca.crt` file.
4. I will use `openssl` to put `.crt` and `.key` file to `.p12` archive
5. I will use `keytool` to put `.p12` archive to `keystore` archive.
6. I will use `keytool` to put `ca.crt` file to `truststore` archive

The majority of applications (I'm not sure if Kafka but for example Elasticsearch) that support SSL have some built-in tooling to help you set up your own certification authority and certificates for development/testing purposes. They are not meant for production but I think plenty of people use them that way.anyway.

Comment: tahnk you so much your explanations are very clear and simple enough for me to understand them :) . many thanks for taking that time as it will help me a lot for my work